# Проблема с роутингом при использовании ангуляра для части сайта. Ломает URL при обновлении несколько раз

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Доброго времени суток! Возник вопрос касательно AngularJS (1.6). Имеется написанное приложение, которое использует достаточно стандартный роутинг по типу

```
routeProvider.when("/template1", {
        template: template1,
        controller: "template1Ctrl"
    }).when("/template2", {
        template: template2,
        controller: "template2Ctrl"
    }).when("/template3", {
        template: template3,
        controller: "template3Ctrl"
    }).when("/template2/:paramName", {
        redirectTo: "/template3"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/template1"
    });
```

И все вроде бы хорошо, но возникает следующая ситуация. Так уж получилось, что приложение не использует ангуляр глобально, а только в данном куске подрубается через angular.bootstrap(). 
И при приходе на страницу URL содержит некоторые дополнительные данные.
Т.е. урл типа `http://goougle.com/template1?param1=iwantcofeee&howMuch=2`.

При включении ангуляра через бустрап и при проходе через роутинг, ангуляр решает что 1) такого пути нет, значит топаем по otherwise роуту. 2) Редирект получается добавлением (!) к урлу вот такой вот строки -> #/template1.

Т.е. в итоге получаем урл ->`http://goougle.com/template1?param1=iwantcofeee&howMuch=2#/template1`. 
И отсюда начинаются проблемы. Если страницу перезагрузить, то роутинг начинает сходить с ума и сносит все параметры (приводит урл к состоянию `http://goougle.com/template1` в лучшем случае или к `http://goougle.com/template1#/template1` в худшем). 
Но после перезагрузки благодаря кешированию, страница возвращается "по памяти" с прошлого шага (не могу обяснить почему так, но так работает). И после 2-ого обновления страницы, браузер закономерно возвращает 404 ,т.к. остальное приложение ничего не знает об этом (т.е. нарушается роутинг уже у "глобального" приложения).

**В нескольких словах о том, что написано выше:**

1. Заходим на страницу -> урл в состоянии
   `http://goougle.com/template1?param1=iwantcofeee&howMuch=2` до
   прогрузки роутинга ангуляра.
2. После прогрузки роутинга ->
   `http://goougle.com/template1?param1=iwantcofeee&howMuch=2#/template1`
3. После обновления страницы ->
       `http://goougle.com/template1#/template1` (страница загружена)
4. После 2ого обновления ->
   `http://goougle.com/template1#/template1` (ошибка 404).

Я понимаю, что звучит как слишком общий вопрос (не работает ;) ). Но тогда я перефразирую вопрос в конкретном случае :

**Как заставить роутер понимать урл с параметрами, чтобы он их не убирал и по возможности мог с ними взаимодействовать?**

p.s. Я читал про state и другие способы, однако я не смог заставить ангуляр дружить с параметрами. Ну и в ангуляре я полный профан - я понимаю что истина кроется или в методе resolve или в чем то подобном. 
Т.е. код типа не помог (параметров у меня много и не должны обрабатываться ангуляром)

```
$stateProvider
        .state('products', {
            url: '/:productId',
            templateUrl: "/dashboard/products.html",
            controller: 'ProductController',
            params: {
                productId: {
                  value: "defaultValue",
                  squash: true // or enable this instead to squash `productId` when empty
                } 
            }
        });
```

Comment: А какой вы роутер используете? Первый пример похож на стандартный роутер ангуляра, а второй уже ui-router.

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что роутер англуяра настроен на работу url с хэшем вида #/template1. Сложно написать ответ, потому что нет примера, и сделать вы его не сможете. Попробуйте погуглить на тему `html5Mode`. Например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо и на этом - попробую посмотреть. Но html5mode просто заменяет весь роут своим (т.е. было `http://goougle.com/template1?param1=iwantcofeee&howMuch=2` - стало `http://goougle.com/template1` )

Comment: @IgorGolovin использую тот, что указан первым . Второй пример указан в качестве "попытки исправить но не помогло" =)

Comment: Ну, вы на шаг приблизились к решению. Получается, ангуляр не заменяет юрл, он убирает параметры. Попробуйте указать параметры в роутинге.

Comment: Все еще не удалось решить проблему... А вообще со стороны SPA правильно ли иметь такие линки вообще ? `http://goougle.com/template1?param1=iwantcofeee&howMuch=2#/template1` Т.е. урл, потом query а потом снова часть урл ... Кажись ошибка кроется тут

Comment: @alexoander SPA подразумевает наличии всего 1 "страницы" т.е. сервер отдает 1 раз приложение и потом оно само работает без перезагрузки. Роутинг в url обычно в таких приложения либо отсутствует вообще либо осуществляется на клеите. У вас же не совсем понятно что происходит. Если параметры `param1=iwantcofeee&howMuch=2` не используются ангуляром никак, а просто корень ангуляр приложения, что это норм используйте навигацию через #. Если же ангуляр должен использовать и менять url, то вам нужен html5 mode.

Comment: @IgorGolovin Дело в том, что я назвал ее SPA, но это псевдо SPA т.к. ангуляр подсоединяется частично. Т.е. вклинивается в другое приложение через .bootstrap метод. Пока работает ангуляр, мне нужно перекидывать эти параметры через все пути следования и сделать так, чтобы при перезагрузке страница не меняла свой URL. Главная проблема именно в том, что роутинг всегда! идет через otherwise путь даже если роут совпадает (подозреваю что из-за параметров) . А в otherwise происходит редирект, который ломает url

Comment: Попробуйте  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
Был бы код можно было бы поиграться...

Comment: @Vitalii Спасибо за ответ - на самом деле я уже переключал между режимами. И как показала практика, чтобы не исчезали параметры из url требуется менять состояния не прибегая к методам перезагрузки роутингов а также при первой загрузке сохранить все параметры (да и сам урл) внутрь скоупа, чтобы потом параметры добавлять мануально при переходах. И действительно html5Mode(false) помогает в этом - он не обнуляет строку при первом роуте. Попытаюсь потом описать тут что получилось в итоге.

Comment: @Vitalii насчет кода - я к сожалению плохо знаю механизм boostrap поэтому написать самодостаточное приложеие наврядли смогу ( в котором еще и урл будет "поломаный").  Например вот тут пример такого же стандартного роутинга - https://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg/

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach я не уверен в правильности комментария. Как же я могу дать ответ, если я его не знаю)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko понял, похоже что автор сам нашел ответ, но не опубликовал его... жаль